# Can I use WSL's ufw as a firewall for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, firewall, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ufw

I recently found out Linux is shipped with `ufw` as a firewall, so I thought if I can use WSL, it will be constantly running as a firewall; I know Windows already has a firewall, but having two wouldn't be so bad, and while it might be a dumb thing, I want to know if it's possible.

Comment: Windows comes with a complex firewall by default: [Windows Firewall](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/windows-firewall-with-advanced-security). Configuring redundant OS firewalls will create more problems than it solves and would only apply to outbound traffic from the OS or inbound traffic from LAN devices; for the latter, it would be more efficient to create a vlan on the router.

Comment: Thanks for moving this over from Stack Overflow.  As I mentioned there, the answer is almost certainly "no".  I've provided some more details on why in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under WSL1, `ufw` will simply refuse to run since it does not contain a "real" Linux networking stack.

Under WSL2, the instance is running in a Hyper-V VM with a virtual NIC that is pseudo-NAT'd *behind* the Windows host network.  `ufw` would likely run just fine, but it would only apply to traffic coming in to the WSL2 instance, not to Windows.  It's like running the firewall on your computer doesn't protect other computers or devices on your network.

You *might* could do some Hyper-V configuration (if you have Windows Pro or higher) to bridge the networks, but I think that would even be unlikely (and perhaps even unsafe).  It's best to rely on the native OS networking layer for firewall rules, rather than try to put a "square peg in a round hole" by shifting this responsibility.

And if you are still thinking you might want to "protect" the WSL instance itself with its own firewall, note that there's really not much reason for that either. WSL is not considered or designed to be a "secure" OS in any case.  For example, you can just run `wsl -u root` to log in to any WSL instance as root without a password.  This is by design.  WSL is a development tool, not an OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you managed to set up a firewall in WSL, it will only pertain to applications
running in WSL. (Personally, I don't know of such a firewall.)

A WSL firewall cannot apply to Windows-native applications,
as WSL is only a guest system on Windows and is dependent on the Windows kernel.

Specifically for using ufw in WSL **1**, I suggest reading the post of
[I can't use ufw on WSL-Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100739/i-cant-use-ufw-on-wsl-ubuntu).

Comment: While the first part of your answer is correct, the askubuntu answer you linked to is no longer relevant under WSL version 2.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds: I specified now above WSL version 1.